# Avro Field name beginning with Numeric/Integer

Tags: java, scala, avro

I want create a Avro schema which would have Column names as 123 or 342 etc. 
I tried to create the schema with numeric names surrounded in "`" as below :

```
 val dataTypeMap = Map(
                    "int"-> Type.INT,
                    "long"->Type.LONG,
                    "java.lang.Double" -> Type.DOUBLE,
                    "java.lang.Boolean" -> Type.BOOLEAN,
                    "java.lang.String"-> Type.STRING
                  )
  val schemaBuilder: SchemaBuilder.FieldAssembler[Schema] = SchemaBuilder.record("test").fields()

  import org.apache.avro.Schema
  import org.apache.avro.SchemaBuilder

  val schema: SchemaBuilder.FieldAssembler[Schema] = SchemaBuilder.record("Telemetry").fields

  val map = Map("`1`"-> 1,"`2`"->true, "`3`"-> 2l,"`4`"->3.0d, "`5`"->"hello")
  val newSchema = map.foldLeft(schema)((x,y)=>{
```

x.name(y._1).`type`(Schema.create(dataTypeMap(y._2.getClass.getCanonicalName))).noDefault()
      }).endRecord()

but failed with below error message:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.avro.SchemaParseException: Illegal initial character: 1
        at org.apache.avro.Schema.validateName(Schema.java:1147)
        at org.apache.avro.Schema.access$200(Schema.java:81)
        at org.apache.avro.Schema$Field.<init>(Schema.java:403)
        at org.apache.avro.SchemaBuilder$FieldBuilder.completeField(SchemaBuilder.java:2124)
        at org.apache.avro.SchemaBuilder$FieldBuilder.completeField(SchemaBuilder.java:2120)
        at org.apache.avro.SchemaBuilder$FieldBuilder.access$5200(SchemaBuilder.java:2034)
        at org.apache.avro.SchemaBuilder$GenericDefault.noDefault(SchemaBuilder.java:2417)
```

Please help
Thanks in Advance

Comment: Please add your code so that we can reproduce your issue, see [MCVE] and [ASK]

Comment: Alternative variable names: `oneTwoThree` resp. `oneHundredTwentyThree`

Comment: Added the code I was trying to use

Answer (score 1):

I think this answers to your problem. You should use a letter as prefix.
I got this from the following link: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AVRO-153

Record, field and enum names must:

- start with [A-Za-z_]
- subsequently contain only [A-Za-z0-9_]

We however don't say anything about namespaces. I propose that namespaces must be a series of dot-delimited identifiers as defined above.

As for encouraged naming conventions, I'd opt for Java's:

namespaces are hierarchical, with the root at left, starting with a reversed domain name.

- namespace elements are lowercase record and enum names are
- capitalized CamelCase field and message names are uncapitalized
- camelCase enum symbols are all-cap acronyms embeeded in names are
- capitalized, e.g., Md5Hash, BaseUrl, etc.